# HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Proxy Error ( Connection refused )

Tags: google-app-engine, ubuntu, python-2.7

I am continuously getting connection Proxy error 502 (connection refused) on Google app engine while running the devserver locally. proxy is by passed for localserver but still its its refusing the connection.

here is what I am getting:

```
HTTPError()
HTTPError()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 250, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/request_rewriter.py", line 311, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 89, in __call__
    self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 225, in _flush_logs
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 328, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 226, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Proxy Error ( Connection refused )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 250, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/request_rewriter.py", line 311, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 89, in __call__
    self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 225, in _flush_logs
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 328, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 226, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "/home/arslan/GAE/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Proxy Error ( Connection refused )
INFO     2013-07-17 20:55:24,534 module.py:595] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I was getting very same error in MS windows, so switched to Ubuntu but still I am getting this. And getting this error after I updated my Google app engine SDK to 1.8.2, previous version was working fine.

Any guess why this is happening ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was using the proxy then and GAE/Python Snippet checks for update before running the server and was unable to locate the update server using proxy. Thats why I was getting that error.
I started using network without proxy and things started working normally :).